# How to apply Maxwell's equations to electromagnetic waves?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, acceleration, maxwell-equations, antennas

You know how antennas work and create EM waves...They oscillate charges which create EM waves

Well I'm not satisfied with that explanation so it would be great if you could use maxwells equation to explain why this happens-

1. Why accelerating charges release electromagnetic waves?
2. why electric and magnetic field detaches from the antenna?

Comment: Related recent question by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/595374/

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liénard–Wiechert_potential) has the potentials and fields of an arbitrarily moving charge.

Comment: A field exists everywhere in space at all times. It cannot “detach” from anything. All it can do is change its values at each point.

Comment: Are you looking for the graduate-student-level explanation, the undergraduate-student-level explanation, or the for-non-physicists explanation?